# how to display random number in flutter

Tags: flutter, random

I need to display a random number in flutter using a function, but when i call it i get error.

```
 void generateRandomNumber() {
                        setState(() {
                          point=pointValue[new Random().nextInt(pointValue.length)];
                        });
                        }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the error is when i call it does not give any result on my app screen

Comment: I am assuming pointValue is your list, do you have any item there?

Comment: yes here is the declaration of list List<int> pointValue = [5,6,7,8,10,15];

Comment: I want to turn this void method to function that return a number on my screen, and i'm very thankful for your time

Comment: @MrFlutter Can you update the question to show more of your code, e.g. showing where this function is called or posting the whole class?

Comment: @socasanta here is the code 
 Text(
         'You have Got',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                            Center(
                            child:Text(
                              generateRandomNumber().toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.greenAccent,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 60,fontFamily: 'CM Sans Serif')),
                          ),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return int value from your method which generated by `Random` class

```
 List<int> pointValue = [5,6,7,8,10,15];
  
  int generateRandomNumber() {
    return pointValue[new Random().nextInt(pointValue.length)];
  }
```

Comment: Thaaanks a lot, i change the code like you but when i call generateRandomNumber() i get the error 'The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.'

Comment: generateRandomNumber();
                            Center(
                            child:Text(
                              'elements',
                              style:
                              TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontFamily: 'muso',
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                            ),
                            )

Comment: generateRandomNumber().toString() instead of 'elements'.

Comment: Thaaaaaank you you save my day

Comment: Hi,
can you help me please i have a problem that i don't know how can i get the result that i get on this screen to another screen.

Comment: @MrFlutter: Please ask the question on SO, I am happy to help you